# Import column from another table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I made API with Django Restframework.

[models.py]

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    article_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='1234')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    article_no = models.ForeignKey('Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='1234')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

[views.py]

```
class ArticleDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, article_no, format=None):
        try:
            article = models.Article.objects.get(article_no=article_no)
            serializer = serializers.ArticleDetailSerializer(article)

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data)
        except models.Article.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

[urls.py]

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('article/<int:article_no>', views.ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
]
```

[serializers.py]

```
class ArticleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    comment = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = (
            'article_no',
            'content',
            'password',
            'date',
            'comment',
        )
```

In `serializers.py`, I defined `comment = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` and add it to fields.

And to test it, I add comment for article_no=1

But When I connect to /article/1, comment doesn't show anything.

[image]

I want to show all comments related it's article_no.

How can I fixed it?

Thanks.

---

Fixed source is here.

[serializers.py]

```
class ArticleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = (
            'article_no',
            'content',
            'password',
            'date',
            'comments',
        )
```

[models.py]

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article_no = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='1234')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I connect to my server,

[image]

It only shows related comment's article_no.

But I want to show content and date also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Django documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects you can access the list of objects by calling `article_instance.comment_set.all()` or you could set the `related_name` argument on the model on initialization

```
article_no = models.ForeignKey('Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
```

and access is like `article_instance.comments.all() or filter() or exclude()`

There are quite a few options actually, and it depends on the use case, but for simplicity, in this case you may be able to just change the `comment` variable to `comment_set`, or you could change the related_name to `comments` and refer to it as such in your serializer.

required changes to ArticleDetailSerializer...

```
comment = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

to

```
comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

You also haven't created a CommentSerializer class, or you haven't posted it to the question.

example CommentSerializer....

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        exclude=('article_no',)
```

I exclude the article_no and the remaining fields should be handled due to the assigned defaults on the django models.

The related object manager in Django returns a queryset that can be acted on like any other queryset. So you will want to consider whether an article might have an absurd amount of comments and limit the returned amount.

you can also use a `SerializerMethodField` and have more control over the returned queryset

```
comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_comments(self, obj):
    comments = obj.comments/comment_set.all()[:20] #return the first 20 comments
    return CommentSerializer(comments/comment_set, many=True, read_only=True).data
```

now add `comments/comment_set` to the class `Meta/fields` tuple

Comment: I added related_name='comments' in models.py's Comment class and also added comments to fields in serializers.py. But it only shows article_no. How can I determine specific column to show?

Comment: can you paste the code for the `CommentSerializer` class?

Comment: I added my fixed source code to my post. Please check it.

Comment: it is returning the default which is the id of the comment because you haven't defined a serializer to consume the comments related queryset. On initialization it should be `comments=CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`. 

 Now you must make a CommentSerializer class with all fields except for article_no. below is an example

`class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           exclude= ('article_no',)`

the defaults assigned to your model instance should carry over for the fields

Comment: I got it! It works perfectly. But I want to know that, I used `CommentSerializer` not only ArticleDetail but also another function. So, some function have to display all columns(include `article_no`) but some function have to exclude article_no. In this situation, I have to made some duplicate Serializer and refer it? Is it right way?

Comment: If `function A` and `function B` refer to CommentSerializer. And `function A` have to show `article_no`, But  `function B` doesn't have to show `article_no`. In this case, copy `CommentSerializer`(exclude article_no) to `CommentDetailSerializer`(do not exclude article_no) is the right way?

Comment: you're right, there are situations where you will want to get the article reference while retrieving a comment, again there are lots of ways to do this. You would need a new `ArticleSerializer` without the `comments` property and a new `ExtendedCommentSerializer `that either lists all of the fields or uses the `fields='__all__'. In either the latter or former case, you need to add `article_no=NewArticleSerializer(read_only=True)` to the class definition

Comment: I understand exactly. Thanks for reply :)